# Custom Option File Value Json not decoding

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, file-upload

I am trying to get the path of a Custom Option File. It is contained inside of the option_value index. It looks like this.

```
a:10:{s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:5:"title";s:25:"the-goose-will-attack.jpg";s:10:"quote_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:10:"order_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/order/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:8:"fullpath";s:102:"/var/www/mageprodcory/mage-webroot/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:4:"size";s:5:"42421";s:5:"width";i:450;s:6:"height";i:600;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"94b0992d58b4478d13a2";s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:3:"133";s:3:"key";s:20:"94b0992d58b4478d13a2";}}}
```

As I understand, this is suppose to be JSON that can be decoded, but it looks like something is wrong with it, some characters seem encoded incorrectly. I don't think ;s:25 and such is suppose to be there.

I've tried disabling magic quotes, but that's not the cause.

Any idea why the JSON is incorrect, or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually not a JSON. It is serialized. The `unserialize` function will work.

```
var_dump(unserialize('a:10:{s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:5:"title";s:25:"the-goose-will-attack.jpg";s:10:"quote_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:10:"order_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/order/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:8:"fullpath";s:102:"/var/www/mageprodcory/mage-webroot/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:4:"size";s:5:"42421";s:5:"width";i:450;s:6:"height";i:600;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"94b0992d58b4478d13a2";s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:3:"133";s:3:"key";s:20:"94b0992d58b4478d13a2";}}}'));
```

Credit goes to alexander.polomodov

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35870803/3774582